# Determining the size of a webpage response using Scala

Tags: http, scala

I have an assignment where I need to determine how much cache space will be required to store the contents of a webpage, and I have to do it all in Scala, which I'm in the process of learning. I know I can get the required information with a HTTP HEAD request, but from what I've read it seems I need an external library for that.

Is it possible to download the HTTP header without using an HTTP request and extract the required information using only Scala (no calls to Java code)?

Comment: The Server you ask fo this information most likely only understands the HTTP protocol and there is (as you already know) a method especially for this case. So I would say: No, there is no way. Why the restriction not to use java classes?

Comment: @drexin, the tutor said "Scala provides an elegant solution to the problem", so the preferred solution would use only Scala.

Comment: http://dispatch-classic.databinder.net/Two+Handlers+Are+Better+Than+One.html ?

Comment: Can you use Scala libraries or just the language itself?

Comment: @RomainSertelon, libraries are allowed provided they come with the download from http://www.scala-lang.org/

Comment: OK, so just Scala then, no 3rd party libraries. You can use `Source.fromURL` to get the page, and then get the size of the page.

Comment: @RomainSertelon, that was exactly what I was after. If you write it up as an answer I'll give you the credit for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need not use 3rd party libraries, then the solution might be to use `Source.fromURL` to get the page and then compute its size.

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Without your restriction that only Scala may be used I would have said: use [Async-Http-Client](http://sonatype.github.com/async-http-client/request.html#contentBox)'s `AsyncHandler` and stop as soon as `onHeadersReceived` has been called.

Without external libraries, you could try to mimic what a HTTP client is doing. Here's a sample `telnet` session:

```
$ telnet www.google.com 80
HEAD / Trying 173.194.40.20...
Connected to www.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.ch/
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=c2b92507b9088226:FF=0:TM=1361870408:LM=1361870408:S=mbY_Qws86Z75gPAk; expires=Thu, 26-Feb-2015 09:20:08 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
Set-Cookie: NID=67=dAFEWKT5vk9HWP1sTF6Oo49jv0sRV7_49ewSgD3fYRiTjHqlUasKl7Jz86SnJhtS-o9zU9raxwCLhdfvEwdwl9imRwONMBTDBKDXtJhFufLCnAoOKgDQetv0A5FTN3Da; expires=Wed, 28-Aug-    2013 09:20:08 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
Date: Tue, 26 Feb 2013 09:20:08 GMT
Server: gws
Content-Length: 218
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

(What I typed was `HEAD / HTTP/1.1`, `Host: www.google.com`, and an additional return.)

You could try to use the JVM's [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) class to open a TCP connection to your server and send, as in the example above, the HEAD request yourself.